# При нажатии на клавишу Enter должна сработать кнопка JButton

Tags: java, swing, события

Как реализовать на java, чтобы при нажатии на <kbd>Enter</kbd> срабатывала кнопка?

Comment: Необходимо чтобы на этой кнопке(JButton) был фокус в момент нажатия Enter.

Comment: моя задача скорее всего решается при помощи "Listener" только я не знаю как его использовать

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то тебе надо добавить ActionListener и в нём прописать необходимые тебе действия.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете просто сделать вашу кнопку "кнопкой по умолчанию":

```
JRootPane rootPane = SwingUtilities.getRootPane(/* ваша кнопка  */); 
rootPane.setDefaultButton(/* ваша кнопка */);
```

Comment: О Хорошо! а я думал уже гуглить коды кнопки и сравнивать по номеру кода...

Comment: кнопка стала выделенной, как кнопка по умолчанию, только вот при нажатии на "Enter" все равно ничего не происходит...

Comment: У вас какое-нибудь текстовое поле не заглатывает Enter? http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JFramesetDefaultButtonJButtonbnRemoveEnterkeystrokefromJTextField.htm

Comment: дело в том что у меня форма авторизации, и после того как я ввел логин и пароль мне нужно мышкой нажимать кнопку "Авторизоваться" (нет не заглатывает)

Comment: Athari тот код что вы привели выше работает, только перед тем как нажать Enter нужно табом выделить нужную кнопку (это можно реализовать без нажатия "Tab"?)

Comment: @Вова Вы попробовали выпилить Enter из кеймапа текстовых полей, как в приведённой ссылке?

Answer (score 1):

Может попробуешь робота?

```
try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();

        // Симулирует клик по кнопке
        robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

        // Симулирует нажатие
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

} catch (AWTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

[Вопрос на англоязычном сайте](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745959/how-to-simulate-keyboard-presses-in-java)